# Extension of Wahba's problem: finding two unknown rotations surrounding a known rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations, rotations

[Wahba's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem) seeks to find the $3\times3$ rotation matrix which minimises:

$$ J(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k}|| \boldsymbol{{w}}_k - \boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}\boldsymbol{v}_k||^2 $$

I have a similar but potentially more difficult problem, where my transformation between two vectors is given by

$$ \boldsymbol{w}_k \approx \boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}_1\, \boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}_{2,k}\, \boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}_3\, \boldsymbol{v}_k $$
where $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}_{2,k}$ is a known Euler rotation about two axes, and $k=1, 2, \cdots, N$.

I wish to determine the best fit rotations $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}_1$, and $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{R}}_3$ which describe the two sets of vectors.

With the exception of using a large set of data in a nonlinear optimisation, is there any way to estimate these two rotation matrices?

Any help is appreciated - Thank you!

Comment: If there are no restrictions on $R_1$ or $R_3$, then we can attain any possible rotation $R$ with the product $R = RR_{2,k} R_{2,k}^{-1}$, which means that this problem is equivalent to Wahba's problem

Comment: Thanks @Ben. However (if I understand your solution correctly), $\boldsymbol{R}_1$ abd $\boldsymbol{R}_3$ are constant, whereas $\boldsymbol{R}_{2,k}$ varies with each corresponding $\boldsymbol{w}_k$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_k$. So I don't think your solution will fit this problem.

Comment: You have misunderstood. $R_1$ varies, $R_3$ is held constant (and of course $R_{2,k}$ is kept equal to its known value). If $R_1$ is allowed to be an arbitrary rotation, then varying $R_3$ provides no further flexibility in the nature of the transformation.

Comment: Sorry @Ben, I probably didn't make it clear in the question. $\boldsymbol{R}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{R}_3$ are fixed for all $k$. So $\boldsymbol{R}_1$ cannot be changed to be the inverse of $\boldsymbol{R}_{2,k}$ for each $k$.

Comment: I understand now. Your question was clear, I just misread it; sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\skew#1{\,\left[\,#1\,\right]_\times}
\def\zz{0\;\,}
\def\bx{\boxtimes}
$The first step is to collect the $v_k\LR{{\rm and}\;w_k}$ vectors into the columns of a matrix
$$\eqalign{
V &= \m{\:v_1 & \:v_2 & \ldots & \:v_n} &\;=\; \sum_k v_ke_k^T \\
W &= \m{w_1 & w_2 & \ldots & w_n} &\;=\; \sum_k w_ke_k^T \\
}$$
where $e_k$ denote the canonical basis vectors.

The Frobenius product can be defined in terms of the trace
$${ A:B = \trace{A^TB} }$$
while the Khatri-Rao $(\bx)$ product is the column-wise Kronecker $(\otimes)$ product
$$\eqalign{
U &= \m{u_1\,&u_2&\ldots&\,u_n} \\
U &= {V\bx W} \quad\iff\; u_k = {v_k\otimes w_k} \\
}$$
and has the following occasionally useful property
$$\eqalign{
\vecc{W\,\Diag{x}\:V^T} = \LR{V\bx W} x \;=\; Ux \\
}$$

Define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\R{R_b^T\otimes R_a}
\def\Rab{R_p}
Q_k &= R_a\,R_k\,R_b &\qiq Q_k^TQ_k = I \\
s_k &= \vecc{R_k} &\qiq S = \sum_k s_ke_k^T \\
M &= -2\,US^T \\
\Rab &= \R &\qiq \Rab^T\Rab = I \\
}$$

---

Use the above ideas to rewrite the cost function
$$\eqalign{
\def\J{J_0}
J &= \sum_k \LR{w_k - Q_kv_k}^T\LR{w_k - Q_kv_k} \\
 &= \sum_k \LR{w_k^Tw_k - 2w_k^TQ_kv_k + v_k^Tv_k} \\
\J &= \LR{J-\sum_k \LR{w_k^Tw_k + v_k^Tv_k}} \\
 &= -2\sum_k w_k:Q_kv_k \\
 &= -2\sum_k We_k:Q_kVe_k \\
 &= -2\sum_k W\LR{e_ke_k^T}V^T:Q_k \\
 &= -2\sum_k W\Diag{e_k}V^T : R_aR_kR_b \\
 &= -2\sum_k \LR{V\bx W}e_k : \LR{R_b^T\otimes R_a}s_k \\
 &= -2\LR{V\bx W}: \LR{R_b^T\otimes R_a}\sum_k s_ke_k^T  \\
 &= -2U:\Rab\, S  \\
 &= M:\Rab \\
}$$
Now proceed as per the usual Orthogonal Procrustes Problem, i.e.

compute the SVD of $M$, then $\Rab$ equals the product of the orthogonal factors.

The only twist is that you must decompose $\Rab$ back into
$R_a\;{\rm and}\;R_b$

### Update

I don't know what your data looks like, however it seems unlikely that $\Rab$ will factor neatly into two orthogonal matrices.

Instead, you can partition $M$ into $3\times 3$ blocks, distribute the Frobenius product, and calculate the differential of the cost function like so
$$\eqalign{
\def\Sj{\sum_j} \def\Sk{\sum_k}
\def\Mjk{{M}_{jk}}
\def\Ejk{E_{jk}}
\def\Ekj{E_{kj}}
\Ejk &= e_je_k^T \;=\; \Ekj^T \\
M &= \Sj\Sk \Ejk\otimes\Mjk \\
\\
\J &= \LR{\Sj\Sk \Ejk\otimes\Mjk}:\LR{R_b^T\otimes R_a} \\
 &= \Sj\Sk\LR{\Ekj:R_b}\LR{\Mjk:R_a} \\
\\
d\J &= \LR{\Sj\Sk\LR{\Ekj:R_b}\Mjk}:dR_a
 \;+\; \LR{\Sj\Sk\LR{\Mjk:R_a}\Ekj}:dR_b \\
 &= G_a:dR_a \;+\; G_b:dR_b \\
}$$
The problem is that $R_a\;{\rm and}\;R_b$ are orthogonal matrices, which constrains the directions of
$dR_a\;{\rm and}\;dR_b$ in complicated ways.

However, a rotation matrix can be constructed from an **unconstrained** vector

via the Rodrigues formula
$$\eqalign{
\def\E{\color{red}{\cal E}}
\skew{b} &= -\E\cdot b = \mc{
 \zz & -b_3 &  b_2 \\
 b_3 &  \zz & -b_1 \\
-b_2 &  b_1 &  \zz \\
} \\
R_b &= \exp(\skew{b})\\
}$$
where $\E$ is the [Levi-Civita](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) tensor.

A paper by [Yezzi-Gallego](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0788.pdf) contains an amazing formula
for differentiating $R_b$
$$\eqalign{
\def\g{{\large g}}
Y_b &= \frac{bb^T + \LR{R_b^T-I}\skew b}{b^Tb} \\
dR_b &= -\LR{R_b\cdot\E\cdot Y_b}\cdot db \\
}$$
Substituting this into the differential of the cost function yields
$$\eqalign{
d\J &= &-\LR{G_a:\LR{R_a\cdot\E\cdot Y_a}}\cdot da \\
  & &-\LR{G_b:\LR{R_b\cdot\E\cdot Y_b}}\cdot db \\
\grad{\J}{a} &= &\g_a \;=\; -{G_a:\LR{R_a\cdot\E\cdot Y_a}} \\
\grad{\J}{b} &= &\g_b \;=\; -{G_b:\LR{R_b\cdot\E\cdot Y_b}} \\
}$$
These unconstrained vector gradients can be used in an Alternating Least Squares iteration scheme to find optimal $\LR{a,b}$ vectors such that $\,\g_a=\g_b=0,\:$ and the corresponding rotation matrices can be constructed from the optimal vectors.

Note that dot products and double-dot (Frobenius) products
extend to tensors
$$\eqalign{
\def\A{{\cal A}}
\def\B{{\cal B}}
\def\C{{\cal G}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\F{{\cal F}}
\F &= \A\cdot\B &\qiq \F_{a\ldots j\,\ell\ldots z}
   = \Sk\A_{a\ldots j\c{k}}\,\B_{\c{k}\ell\ldots z} \\
\C &= \A:\B &\qiq \C_{a\ldots i\,\ell\ldots z}
   = \Sj\Sk\A_{a\ldots i\c{jk}}\,\B_{\c{jk}\ell\ldots z} \\
}$$